# get data from file with fseek() php

Tags: php, file, fseek

i have a data from file, like this:

> 1234567890abcde1234567890

I want to take some specific data from these data. So I get value : "abcde", which the data is located at 11-15. Here, I use fseek() in php and output that appears is :

> Resource id #3

Here is the code that makes the output as above :

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('data/tes.txt', 'r');

// read some data
$data = fgets($fp, 25);

// move back to the beginning of the file
// same as rewind($fp);
fseek($fp, 11);
echo $fp;

?>
```

whereas, I want to take the data at position 11-15. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You made very easy mistake you echo the resource instead of data.

Change

```
fseek($fp, 11);
echo $fp;
```

to

```
echo fseek($fp, 11);
```

remember that fseek upon success, returns 0; otherwise, returns -1. If you want to search the data the better solution would be to use preg_match

```
<?php
  $data = file_get_contents("data/tes.txt");
  $matches = array();
  preg_match("/[a-z]+/", $data, $matches);
  print_r($matches);
?>
```

Try the code above. You can also use substr() function if you want to cut the string from/to specific position.

```
  <?php
    $data = file_get_contents("data/tes.txt");
    echo substr($data, 11, 4);
  ?>
```

Comment: oh im sorry, I just realized that I was wrong print variable.
Beside that, if i use substr(), i dont get data previous position 11.
So, actually. I have a variable that stores the value of a position, where I will be taking 5 positions and 5 after the previous position.
when referring to the data, then I can get the values​​:
Left -> abcde and right -> 23456
do you have a solution? thanks master.

Comment: put your data onto your post. The solution is simple, just juse preg_match or preg_match_all with subpatterns. I need to know how the data looks like

Comment: so, essentially I have a file / data contents of a string to a certain length (approximately 5 million strings -> ....acgtccagt...). For example, there is information to position 150, and I was asked to take a position before the contents at 10 and 10 positions later (139-149 and 151-161). how do I retrieve that value?

Comment: php.net/substr "Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters" so `substr($str, 139, 10);` and `substr($str, 151, 10); `